# How to use multiple databases with SQLite and C# in the same windows application

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am developing a Winforms application which handles multi user and multi company concept. If a user enters in a company and open something, like accounts, it displays that data in a datagridview, but when user switches company inside the app, it also switches the SQLite database file.

Comment: If using entity framework install a visual studio extension called EF Core Power Tools, when you use it to help create your database access, do each database in its own class library project if you're doing database first and reverse engineering each time you make a change

Comment: sorry for that... question is in the head...  I forgot to type in body.